# What should i use to detect a specific person in a crowd?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, robotics

Currently I'm doing a robot that will follow me with hand gestures. However, the robot could not differentiate if there is a person beside me doing the similar hand gesture as I did.

May I ask what I should do to allow the robot to just follow only my hand gesture?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: use face recognition and tracking,  like its been use in drones now a days

Comment: What you have detected is a bug. The wanted behavior is, that the tracking algorithm stays on a certain hand, while in reality the algorithm is switching back and forth between all the hands in the video. I would guess that the filter is searching for a pattern which looks like a hand, and if he detects many of them he will surround all the hands with a marker. It is not a bug in a classical sense, instead it is a very interesting feature which has to be described in detail. Has this phenomena a name (e.g. overfiltering), was this problem described in the literature?

Comment: No it was a robot that was build together with my group mates. The problem is discovered by ourselves. Let me add in more info about the robot, so when we do a hand gesture, the robot will follow me even i back face it. So i don't think the face recognition will work either.
Currently the only idea is some kind of a device that is able to locate that specific person, but if possible i would not want to use this idea.

Comment: Slowly but targeted we are approaching the problem. It is a vision based hand-gesture tracking algorithm which makes problems in detecting a certain person in the video. Hand-gesture recognition is widely discussed in the literature, but usually under the precondition that only a single person is in the videostream. Extending this to a crowd is a bit tricky and is discussed in the literature under the term “Crowd Tracking” and “Crowd Event Recognition”. The idea is, that the robot monitors the visitors group and decides, which of the person is in charge of taking commands.

Comment: Not sure whether the standards in the `artificial-intelligence` tag are a bit different here, but the question seems a bit too broad, no? Maybe you should try asking the question on [Artificial Intelligence Stack Exchange](https://ai.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: This paper probably does what you want: https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/7554324